# Searching a PDF in Adobe Acrobat and Reader returns incorrect results

Tags: pdf, search, adobe-acrobat

Using Control-f or the binoculars icon to search for a word takes you to random points in the file.

Comment: This happened to me, so I'm putting it here for future reference:  The problem is that the local Adobe Search cache is corrupted.  Open the Preferences dialog (Ctrl-K or Menu: Edit/Preferences).  Choose Search, click "Purge Cache contents" or even uncheck "Enable fast find".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering myself: The problem is that the local Adobe Search cache is corrupted. Open the Preferences dialog (Ctrl-K or Menu: Edit/Preferences). Choose Search, click "Purge Cache contents" or even uncheck "Enable fast find".